# Delete button doesn't work on my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, datagrid, onclick

I created delete function for delete button but it doesn't work. I looked at the example and the code is almost identical but somehow it's not working out for me. Are there any suggestions?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./userList.scss";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { userColumns, userRows } from "../../datatablesource";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const Datatable = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(userRows);

  const deleteData = id => {
    setData(data.filter(item => item.id !== id));
  };

  const actionColumn = [
    {
      field: "action",
      headerName: "Action",
      width: 200,
      renderCell: params => {
        return (
          <div className="cellAction">
            <Link to="/users/profile" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
              <button className="viewButton">View</button>
            </Link>
            <button className="deleteButton" onClick={() => deleteData(params.row.id)}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="datatable">
      <DataGrid rows={userRows} columns={userColumns.concat(actionColumn)} pageSize={5} rowsPerPageOptions={[5]} checkboxSelection disableSelectionOnClick />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Datatable;
```

Here is the data for userRows. It has it's id property which i use it for delete function.

```
export const userRows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    username: "Snow",
    img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1820770/pexels-photo-1820770.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
    status: "active",
    email: "1snow@gmail.com",
    age: 35
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    username: "Jamie Lannister",
    img: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1820770/pexels-photo-1820770.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500",
    email: "2snow@gmail.com",
    status: "passive",
    age: 42
  }
];
```

Here is the data for userColumns:

```
export const userColumns = [
  {
    field: "id",
    headerName: "ID",
    width: 70
  },
  {
    field: "user",
    headerName: "Username",
    width: 250,
    renderCell: params => {
      return (
        <div className="cellWithImg">
          <img className="cellImg" src={params.row.img} alt="avatar" />
          {params.row.username}
        </div>
      );
    }
  },
  {
    field: "email",
    headerName: "Email",
    width: 280
  },
  {
    field: "age",
    headerName: "Age",
    width: 100
  },
  {
    field: "status",
    headerName: "Status",
    width: 160,
    renderCell: params => {
      return <div className={`cellWithStatus ${params.row.status}`}>{params.row.status}</div>;
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: Stating delete button is not working for me won't tell us the problem or error. Please include how it's not working for you. Are there any errors? Or what you expected is not the result.

Answer (score 1):

*First*:
use state value (data) in rows props in the Datagrid

```
<DataGrid rows={data} columns={userColumns.concat(actionColumn)} pageSize={5} rowsPerPageOptions={[5]} checkboxSelection disableSelectionOnClick />
```

*second*:

### ***Q)*** **How to update state value in react js ?**

In delete function you are updating the state value and to update the state this approach is not the correct one.
correct way to update the state is this

1. use callback function where you get the previous value of the state
2. then filter the array as you have done
3. then destructure the array to create the clone of that array to update the state
   value

   ```
   const deleteData = (id) => {
   setData((d) => {
     return [...d.filter((item) => item.id !== id)];
   });}
   ```

Comment: thank you very much man. this solution worked. I realized that if I used userRows as the rows, it always rendered the whole userRows data after i clicked delete.